# Matroids which are transitive on minimal basis exchanges

Tags: matroid-theory, symmetry, polytopes, classification

I am looking for matroids in which all *minimal basis exchanges* look the same, that is, the matroid is *transitive* on these. Let me explain what I mean by that.

Consider a finite matroid $M$. Define a graph $G_M$ as follows:

- The vertices of $G_M$ are the bases of $M$.
- Two bases are connected by an edge in $G_M$ if you can obtain one from the other by only exchanging a single element.

> **Question:** Does there exist a classification of the matroids $M$ for which $G_M$ is edge-transitive or [arc-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph), that is, a classification of matroids that are transitive on minimal basis exchanges?

I know of some such matroids, as their [matroid polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_polytope) are highly symmetric. E.g. the ones for which the matroid polytope is a

- [Hypersimplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersimplex) (belong to the uniform matroids).
- $n$-cube or $n$-orthoplex.